# Basic Infinite Series Question: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n+4^n}{6^n}=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

The question:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n+4^n}{6^n}=\;?$$

I can't figure out how to approach this question as I can't find a constant value for $r$.

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7B2%5En%2B4%5En%7D%7B6%5En%7D%24&p=1) if ound these very similar questions:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418002/infinite-series-sum-cant-find-the-geometric-series-sum-i-0-infty-2i-4 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753313/finding-the-sum-of-series-sum-n-0%E2%88%9E-frac2n-3n6n

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.**
$$\frac{2^n+4^n}{6^n} =  \frac{2^n}{6^n}+\frac{4^n}{6^n} = \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^n+\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$$

Comment: What? You have that

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n + 4^n}{6^n} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac13\right)^n + \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac23\right)^n$$
by the calculation in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Split up the summand into $(\frac{2}{6})^n + (\frac{4}{6})^n = (\frac{1}{3})^n + (\frac{2}{3})^n$

That's the sum of two geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Write this as the sum of two geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Use this law:
$$ \sum a+b = \sum a +\sum b $$

You get
$$ \sum \frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{6^{n}} = \sum \frac{2^{n}}{6^{n}} +\sum \frac{4^{n}}{6^{n}} $$
$$=\sum (\frac{2}{6})^{n} + \sum (\frac{4}{6})^{n}$$

where your two r values are 2/6 and 4/6